How to test a condition with instanceof String with Sinon
I have a JS code that is like below:
const handleCommunication = () => {
window.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
  if (!message.data instanceof String) {
    const { topic, event } = message.data;
      ....

This is my test case:
const test = require('ava');
const rewire = require('rewire');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const handleCom = rewire('../handleCommunication .js');

test.afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
});

test.beforeEach(() => {

global.window = {
    addEventListener: (topic, callback) => {
        if (topic === 'message') {
            callback({ data: { topic: 'XXX', event: { header: { TEST: 'abc' } } } });
        }
    }
};
});

test('handleCommunication test', (t) => {
    handleCom.__get__('handleCommunication ');
    //t.truthy(something.called);
});

The problem is for the line
if (!message.data instanceof String) {

I dont know how to mock this line, because it is the first condition for the function, the whole function is not covered. How can I mock this line? I tried to comment out this line and I got 100% coverage.
